# Applying synchronization filter, can it affect All Contacts count?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder, contact-deletion

We have been using the Marketing Cloud Connect for a few months. However, during the initial sync we did not turn on any filters, which resulted in having over 1 million records in our synchronized data extension of the Account object (we are not using the Contact object). Fast-forward to today, after turning on a relevant ID filter (email consent), the number was greatly reduced to 80,000. However, in All Contacts menu, the billable count is still showing 1 million. Since we did it today, does it take time for the billable number of contacts to decrease in the All Contacts section over the next few hours/days to 80k, or is the 1 million count going to remain until we manually delete the surplus contacts via API or something? Mind you, we have not sent any emails beyond the 80k we have consent for communication. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. If you filter or update the filter or delete it will get updated in synchronise data extension. But it won't reduce the contact count.

You can do it with an API or just import the data from salesforce to marketing cloud. Go to Contact Builder in the All Contacts tab, click on the Delete can icon in the top right of the page and choose “Delete contacts from data extension”. Select your data extension you created then click the delete contacts button.

Note if this is a new org you would need to enable contact deletion. Please follow the link - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_enable_contact_delete.htm&type=5

Hope this helps.

Comment: Support doesn’t need to enable contact deletion

Comment: Thanks Naveen! And for this contact deletion, does this data extension has to contain anything else other than the Contact Key (e.g. email) ?  Also, if I would re-sync the Contact object again just to get the data for for import into the deletion data extension, would this result in duplicates or does SFMC recognize the same contact key and does de-duplication during sync ?

Comment: @nix9247, you would need only contact key others are optional. You can do re-sync get the contacts, update the filter and post that you can delete. If you delete and change the filter, then contacts count will be back to the same. To your last question, if you re-sync it SFMC recognize it will be the same contact key. It won't result in duplicate. Thanks EazyE for your comment , i have updated my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks again Naveen